# how can I use IMAGE type field in c# core web

Tags: c#, sql-server, web

> MsSQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees] (
   ...
    [Photo]           IMAGE          NULL,
  ...
);
```

How can I use [Displayname ..

> c#  (xxrow.cs )

```
        [DisplayName("Photo" ) , Size(1073741823) ]  ***<---????***
         public Stream Photo
        {
            get => fields.Photo[this];
            set => fields.Photo[this] = value;
        }
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "**IMPORTANT!** **ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work"

Comment: Don't. Use `varbinary(max)` if you really must or, even better, store the pictures in online storage (S3, Azure blob, etc.) or the filesystem and only keep a reference to the picture in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you cannot do this.
Image Type in Sql Server column contains binary data == the content of the image (pixel by pixel). It doesn't contains the name of the source of the image.
Perharps another columun in your table contains the source name of the image.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your support. But he may have asked the question wrong. Actually, my problem is that an image type field in databse cannot be displayed on my system on the screen and I cannot upload it. I guess I don't know how to do it.
Actually, although I am old as a programmer, I am an amateur in .netcoreweb(c#)-tscript-Entity.